# How to save a websocket client's connection and send it later with akka-streams and akka-http

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to follow this part of the [`akka-http` documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#handling-messages) where it talks about handling web socket messages asynchronously

What I am trying to do is this:

1. Receive a websocket request for a client
2. Serve a payment invoice back to the client
3. Run a background process that has the client's websocket connection saved, and when the client pays their invoice, send the data they queried about in return ("World") in this case.

Here is the code I have so far

```
def hello: Route = {
  val amt = 1000
  val helloRoute: Route = pathPrefix(Constants.apiVersion) {
  path("hello") {
    val source: Source[Message, SourceQueueWithComplete[Message]] = {
      Source.queue(1, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    }

    val paymentRequest = createPaymentRequest(1000, extractUpgradeToWebSocket)
    Directives.handleWebSocketMessages(
      paymentFlow(paymentRequest)
    )
    }
  }
  helloRoute
}

private def createPaymentRequest(amt: Long, wsUpgrade: Directive1[UpgradeToWebSocket]) = {
    val httpResponse: Directive1[HttpResponse] = wsUpgrade.map { ws =>
      val sink: Sink[Message, NotUsed] = Sink.cancelled()
      val source: Source[Message, NotUsed] = Source.single(TextMessage("World"))
      val x: HttpResponse = ws.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sink, source)
      x
    }
    httpResponse.map { resp =>
      //here is where I want to send a websocket message back to the client
      //that is the HttpResponse above, how do I complete this? 
      Directives.complete(resp)
  }

}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get access to a `RequestContext` or a `UpgradeToWebSocket` outside of the container type `Directive`? And when I map on `httpResponse` the map is not executing.